# Content provider uris from one app to other access

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have created a content uri from one app :

```
content://SendDataProvider/bookevent
```

i am able to insert the values into it.
like :

```
content://SendDataProvider/bookevent/1
content://SendDataProvider/bookevent/2 etc...
```

but when i call it to other app for geting all record from this URI i use

```
String bookContentDataLog = "content://SendDataProvider/bookevent";
Uri bookrecord = Uri.parse(bookContentDataLog);
Cursor cursor = BookShelfActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(
                    bookrecord, null, null, null, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {  // I got Null pointer exception here
                String sessionId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BOOK_COLUMN_SESSIONID));
                String magId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BOOK_COLUMN_MAG_ID));
}
```

I debug it and i found that

```
BookShelfActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(
                    bookrecord, null, null, null, null);
```

this return null value to cursor.

How i get all value inserted to this "content://SendDataProvider/bookevent"?

============== I have Used method to insert to uri ===================
1) Class Name and variables

```
public class SendDataProvider extends ContentProvider {


public SendDataProvider(Context c) {
        this.context = c;//getContext();
        BookDb dbHelper = new BookDb(context);
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
```

2) content provider class methode :===

```
@Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues) throws NullPointerException {
        Log.e("SendDataProvider @Override inserted call","Uri insert");
        long rowID = db.insert(BOOK_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        Log.e("SendDataProvider @Override inserted ID","Uri insert ID"+rowID);
        if (rowID > 0) {
            Uri _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, rowID);
            this.context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);
            return _uri;
        }
        throw new SQLException("Failed to add a record into " + uri);
    }
```

3) query

```
@Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

              SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
              qb.setTables(BOOK_TABLE_NAME);

              switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
              case uriCode:
               qb.setProjectionMap(this.values);
               break;
              default:
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
              }
              if (sortOrder == null || sortOrder == "") {
               sortOrder = BOOK_COLUMN_MAG_ID;
              }
              Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null,
                null, sortOrder);
              c.setNotificationUri(this.context.getContentResolver(), uri);
              return c;
    }
```

Comment: Post the query method of the ContentProvider that you access.

Comment: query not insert !!!

Comment: Please check i have inserted query

Comment: now post full logcat log ... NPE is not in this line ... `qb.query` cannot  will not return null so maybe `qb` is null ...

Comment: SendDataProvider class is ok.. it will work fine...! I call this uris from other app. and i use query methode to get values then cursor get null value. Please read question carefully :(

Comment: please write the question carefully ... there is no chances to get null cursor there unless you did not provide whole code (with try catch blocks)

Comment: what should i do? should i zip and send you the whole code then u understand ? i already told you i am able to insert data to provider uri but i didn't get the result from that uri.

Comment: Failed to find provider info for SendDataProvider

Comment: No one reply answers :( :( :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED :

Step 1: 
create Provider class with DB inser/update/delte/query and be carefull about this things.

```
static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.example.contentprovideruser.DataProvider";//"org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.interfaces.SendDataProvider";
static final String URL = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/bookevent";
static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(URL);
```

You need to create well URI

Step 2: Add **PROVIDER_NAME** AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <provider android:name=".DataProvider" 
       android:authorities="com.example.contentprovideruser.DataProvider"
       android:exported="true"
       android:multiprocess="true">
 </provider>
```

Step 3:Need to specify well MIME TYPE

```
@Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case BOOK:
            return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.booktype";
        case BOOK_ID:
            return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.booktype";
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
        }
    }
```

step 4 :"CONTENT_URI" is your global uri  where all value are inserted

you can use query to get result.

```
Uri students = DataProvider.CONTENT_URI;
          Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(students, null, null, null, "name");
          if (c.moveToFirst()) {
             do{
                Toast.makeText(this, 
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.BOOK_COLUMN_EVENT_NAME)) + 
                ", " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( DataProvider.BOOK_COLUMN_FROMPAGE_NO)), 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             } while (c.moveToNext());
          }
```

BE happy :)

Comment: I ma using a RN module which  name as  .StickerContentProvider" and authorities="${applicationId}.stickercontentprovider" you can see name authorities has same word but different case. Now how would I use it in query.